# How to place a scroll bar for the buttons piled up vertically?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am working on a website in which I want to place a scroll bar for the buttons piled up vertically.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkg4zh68/2/embedded/result) for it.

The html code which I have used in order to make one single button is:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropup
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering how I can placed all the buttons inside the scrollbar. This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
.dropdowns
{
height: 200px;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow) in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<button>btn1</button>
<button>btn2</button>
<button>btn3</button>
<button>btn4</button>
</div>

<style>
div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
 }
 button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
 }
 </style>
```

Above code should work. You can add any bootstrap classes you want for custom look and feel.

Comment: can you update it in the fiddle ? In that way, it would be more to easy to visualize.

Comment: In your fiddle code, just change display: table-cell to display: flex and it will work

Answer (score 0):

here is the fiddle for it

```html
<div>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
</div>

<style>
div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
 }
 button {
 margin:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:green;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 5px;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: Most important thing in this code is height:100px;

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sample Code</title>
    <style>
        div {
            display: flex;
            overflow-x: auto;
            width: 100%;
        }
        button {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border: 1px solid lightblue;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button>btn1</button>
        <button>btn2</button>
        <button>btn3</button>
        <button>btn4</button>
        <button>btn4</button>
        <button>btn5</button>
        <button>btn6</button>
        <button>btn7</button>
        <button>btn8</button>
        <button>btn9</button>
        <button>btn10</button>
        <button>btn11</button>
        <button>btn12</button>
        <button>btn13</button>
        <button>btn14</button>
        <button>btn14</button>
        <button>btn15</button>
        <button>btn16</button>
        <button>btn17</button>
        <button>btn18</button>
        <button>btn19</button>
        <button>btn20</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

dropdowns is display table so you can't set height 200px, you need to set this display is block.

```
.dropdowns{
   height: 200px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   display: block;
}
```